# PHPUnit - trying to test for a key and a value from a json array

Tags: php, json, laravel, phpunit

I have the following Json array:

```json
[
    {
        "ticket_id": 131,
        "ticket_subject": "quasi",
        "ticket_content": "However, everything is queer to-day.' Just then she walked up towards it rather timidly, saying to.",
        "ticket_name": "Prof. Ellen Yost Jr.",
        "ticket_email": "sosinski@example.org",
        "ticket_status": 0,
        "created_at": "2021-04-19 16:53:33",
        "updated_at": "2021-04-19 16:53:33"
    }
]
```

I am trying to write a *feature test* to check that it has 'ticket_status' key  and the corresponding value of `0`.

So far in my tests file, I have the following code:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class OpenTicketTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testOpenTickets()
    {
        $this->get(route('tickets.open'))
            ->assertStatus(200)
            ->assertJsonStructure([
                '*' => [
                    'ticket_id',
                    'ticket_subject',
                    'ticket_content',
                    'ticket_name',
                    'ticket_email',
                    'ticket_status',
                    'created_at',
                    'updated_at'
                ]
            ])->assertJson([
                'ticket_status' => 0
            ]);
    }
}
```

But when I run the test I receive the following error message in the console:

```
Unable to find JSON:

[{
    "ticket_status": 0
}]

within response JSON:

[[]].


Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
    'ticket_status' => 0
).
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 array (
-  'ticket_status' => 0,
 )
```

Anyone has any ideas as to the correct syntax to use in order to retrieve the desired result?

Thanks,

Robert

Comment: There is no problem at all with your test. The test is saying that it is not getting `ticket_status = 0` back, in fact it has `[]` as reply (no data)... So your controller is not okay. Also, if you are doing a test (doesn't matter if it is a unit or feature test) **NEVER** do `route('xxxxx')`, because if the route is `/asdasd` and you don't want that, `route('xxxx')` will still pass it, so you are not asserting correct URL. One more thing, no need to do `assertStatus(200)`, you can directly ignore it, or you can use `assertOk()` (that is `200`) or `assertSuccessful()` (`200` >= status < `300`)

Answer (score 1):

There is no data being returned in your test. You might want to check the reason for that.
Also, you might want to specify the exact JSON structure when trying to assertJson()

```
$this->get(route('tickets.open'))
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure([
            '*' => [
                'ticket_id',
                'ticket_subject',
                'ticket_content',
                'ticket_name',
                'ticket_email',
                'ticket_status',
                'created_at',
                'updated_at'
            ]
        ])->assertJson([
 // assuming this is the json structure
            'data' => [
               0 => 'ticket_status' => 0 // if ticket_status is 0 in the first element
             ] 
        ]);
```